# Rails 4 has_many :through accessing field on join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through

I have 3 models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_leave_portfolios
  has_many :leave_portfolios, :through => :user_leave_portfolios
end

class LeavePortfolio < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_leave_portfolios, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, :through => :user_leave_portfolios
end

class UserLeavePortfolio < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :leave_portfolio

  # this table has an additional field named 'leave_amount'
end
```

The 'leave_amount' field on the user_leave_portfolio table is used as a user chosen leave amount based on a leave_portfolio

According to documentation and various other blogs and articles, I should be able to access the 'leave amount' field with:

```
u = User.first
u.leave_portfolios.first.leave_amount
```

However, I get the following error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `leave_amount' for #LeavePortfolio:0x007f8708e3dbe0

Schema:

```
create_table "leave_portfolios", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name",             limit: 255
  t.integer  "calculation_type", limit: 4
  t.integer  "period",           limit: 4
  t.integer  "default_amount",   limit: 4
  t.integer  "organisation_id",  limit: 4
  t.datetime "created_at",                   null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                   null: false
end

create_table "user_leave_portfolios", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "leave_portfolio_id", limit: 4
  t.integer  "user_id",            limit: 4
  t.float    "leave_amount",       limit: 24
  t.datetime "created_at",                    null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                    null: false
end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "email",                  limit: 255, default: "", null: false
  t.string   "encrypted_password",
  .
  .
  .
end
```

Comment: u.leave_portfolios.first For this you are getting any data? --- check is there any field like leave_amount

Comment: Yes I am. I get a record back. Although, when accessing leave_amount I get "NoMethodError: undefined method `leave_amount'"

Comment: This seems that you have pending migrations. can you share me your schema of related tables?

Comment: I've added it to my post.

Comment: `leave_amount` is in `user_leave_portfolios` not in `leave_portfolios `
So tou can't acces it like that:
`u = User.first
u.leave_portfolios.first.leave_amount`

Comment: I would like to though, I want to access the field on the join table. How would I accomplish this with the has_many :through relationship?

Comment: You should have leave_amount field in leave_portfolios table. make corrections and it will run

Comment: I don't think you understand the problem. Am I trying to do something that other people have solved in another way? I've searched the inter-webs and no one seems to share my problem so it makes me think....

Answer (score 1):

You should do

```
u = User.first
u.user_leave_portfolios.first.leave_amount
```

as you have `leave_amount` in `user_leave_portfolios` not in `leave_portfolios`.